# Firebase realtime database equivalent in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-dynamodb

I am new to AWS. what service in AWS is equivalent to FIrebase realtime database for Android app development. As Firebase has SDK for Android is there any SDK for android in AWS also which can be used for the same?

Answer (score 0):

AWS Amplify is very good option as an alternative to Firebase in AWS services. I have created a video on Firebase alternatives on YouTube. You can watch it at [Firebase Alternatives](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n3nE_JdKobo)